# How to refactor chained $http calls and library call with callback

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have code resembling the following snippet:

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/path/to/route?id=" + id
})
.then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;

    var summary = service.doSomething(data, function (error, result, response) {
        if (error) {
            handleError();
            return;
        }

        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "path/to/another/route?key=" + data.key
        })
        .then(function () {
            // do stuff...
        });
    });

    summary.on("status", function () {
        // do stuff...
    });
})
.catch(function () {
    handleError();
});
```

Is there a way to refactor something like this such that the code isn't nested? In essence, I have three requests which are all dependent on the values obtained by their predecessor. Help?

Comment: Wrap `service.doSomething` into a function that returns a promise. Then you can chain them easily.

Comment: use async / await function

Comment: @AlainIb the ES6 promises created by `async` are not integrated with the AngularJS execution context and its digest cycle. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the call-back based API to a promise:

```
function doSomethingPromise(data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    service.doSomething(data, function (error, result, response) {
    if (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    } else {
        deferred.resolve({result: result, response: response});
    };
    return deferred.promise;
}
```